# How to cache only first segment of the DASH in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to Cache only first segment of the DASH video so, whenever the same video played, For good user experience it starts immediately and in parallel download other segments based on the bandwidth available.

I don't want to cache the complete video because it will be unnecessary blocks the user memory.

Comment: That will be hard to guarantee. Basically, DASH video, as per MPEG-DASH specification consists of `header table` with the list of `segments`. These objects are placed into `containers`. For example, containers are `mp4`, `mkv` etc. These containers are actually getting downloaded. How these pieces are organized and accessible is up to the author of content. All of them can be located in single `container`, which might not be possible to get the video without downloading whole file.

Comment: If pieces are well authored and suitable for caching, then if it would be your player, you theoretically could download `header table` first which is relatively small depending on the size of video and number of segments, then download first few pieces in advance. All can be done asynchronously.

Looking at `exoplayer`, there is a customization possibility. Check for `LoadControl` http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/LoadControl.html

Customizing it, you will be able to pre-load content.

Comment: Also there is a builder for `DefaultLoadControl`, which might be providing enough functionality for your case. http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl.Builder.html

If not, you will have to work with your own implementation of `LoadControl` interface.

Answer (score 0):

ExoPlayer has `Cache` utility, to cache and pre-cache content. [This blog post](https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/pre-caching-downloading-progressive-streams-in-exoplayer-3a816c75e8f6) explains the usage.